# Arbitrary intersection of compact sets in Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a Hausdorff space, and $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ compact subspaces of $X$. Then $\cap_{i \in I}A_i$ is also compact. My proof is as follows:

As $(X, \tau)$ is Hausdorff, every compact subspace is also closed, in particular all of the $A_i$. As the arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed, $\cap_{i \in I}A_i$ is a closed set. But it is a closed set of $A_i$ for some $i \in I$, and closed sets of compact sets are compact, and therefore the intersection is compact. Is it correct?

Comment: It could be better expressed, but the idea is fine.

Comment: Looks good to me