# Intersection of Compact sets is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If $X$ is Hausdorff, and $\{C_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A} $is a collection of sets that are compact in $X$, then $\bigcap_{\alpha \in A}C_\alpha$ is compact in X. I know the proof to the statement should be easy, but I am stuck at how I could use the condition that $X$ is Hausdorff. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in this question: [Arbitrary intersection of compact sets in Hausdorff space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608505).

Comment: Sure. Detailed answers are not hints though; the OP did not want to view the 'duplicate'.

Comment: Actually I read the hints and came up with the exact same proof as in the question mentioned by Anne.

Comment: The answer to your question is: in a Hausdorff space, every compact subset is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: closed subsets of a compact (sub)space are compact

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, which was *how I could use the condition that X
 is Hausdorff*.

Comment: I figured out I just need to use the fact that a compact subset in a Hausdorff space is closed.

Comment: @RunyangWang *That* should indeed have been the answer to your question (and was given in comment above, a few seconds before).

Comment: and now we split hairs over what constitutes a hint? I would argue that leading OP to think about closed sets makes them realise they need each $C_\alpha$ to be closed, which makes them realise how to use the Hausdorff condition